# video-js-contrib-eme can't get initializeMediaKeys to work

Tags: video.js, eme

In our use case, we need to reuse the same license for multiple sources for different videos, I came across the initializeMediaKeys function, but when called with the following emeOptions:

```
var emeOptions = { 
              keySystems : {
                  "com.widevine.alpha": { 
                  url : myUrl,
                  audioRobustness: 'SW_SECURE_CRYPTO',
                  videoRobustness: 'SW_SECURE_CRYPTO'
                  }
              }
      }
```

I've tried several variations of this object as a parameter but I always get a:

```
instrument.js:109 VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:5 MEDIA_ERR_ENCRYPTED) Unsupported keySystem or supportedConfigurations. 
MediaError {code: 5, message: 'Unsupported keySystem or supportedConfigurations.'}
```

And opening the media error object I get:

```
MediaError {code: 5, message: 'Unsupported keySystem or supportedConfigurations.'}
code: 5
message: "Unsupported keySystem or supportedConfigurations."
responseContentType: "application/dash+xml"
responseStatus: 200
responseURL:[REDACTED]
token=[REDACTED]
[[Prototype]]: Object
MEDIA_ERR_ABORTED: 1
MEDIA_ERR_CUSTOM: 0
MEDIA_ERR_DECODE: 3
MEDIA_ERR_ENCRYPTED: 5
MEDIA_ERR_NETWORK: 2
MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED: 4
code: 0
message: ""
status: null
constructor: ƒ MediaError(value)
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Could someone help me or give me a hint? Thanks.

Comment: As an update to this issue, I followed the instructions for setting the options for all sources:


`var options = {
     keySystems: myKeySystems
}
    videoPlayer.eme.options = {
        options
     } `  

And no error is thrown, but the request to the URL for retrieving the license is never made. Therefore the video won't play.
And just to confirm, the exact same `myKeySystems` object works when setting options per source.